# Duda con strcmp en C

Tags: c

Quiero hacer una función para modificar un nombre, clave o correo, de un usuario comparando el nick que ya se ingresó en pasos anteriores, pero siempre me entra en el Else y no entiendo por qué...

```
void modificarUsuarios(sUsuario input[],int cantidad) //sUsuario es el tipo de estructura que estoy utilizando

{
    int i;
    char auxNick[26];


    printf("ingrese Nombre de nick que desea modificar");
    scanf("%s", auxNick);

    for(i=0; i<cantidad; i++)
    { 
        if(strcmp(input[ i ].nickUsuario,auxNick)==0) 
        {
           //desarrollo.
        }
       else
       {

        }
    }
}//termina función
```

Comment: input[] que contiene? sabes que exactamente tiene el mismo nick que ingresas? Tené en cuenta que C las comparaciones de strings son case sensitive.

Comment: input es un parametro de la funcion, en si, es una estructura de tipo usuario donde contiene, nombre, correo, clave y otros datos.. y si, tengo en cuenta lo del case sensitive pero me da falso de todas formas

Comment: ¿Si `sUsuario` es un `struct`, la definición no debería ser: `modificarUsuarios(struct sUsuario input[], int cantidad)` ?

Comment: @NaCl No si se usa un `typedef`

Comment: @LucasMedina ¿Cómo se define y asignan valores a `input[]`? He creado un ejemplo en local ([también disponible online aquí](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c99_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMdWNTc2dEekdTYnM)) usando tu función y me funciona el `if` sin problemas. ¿Podrías crear una [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) y añadirlo a la pregunta?

Comment: Hace un debug en el for, imprimiento input[ i ].nickUsuario y auxNick, son iguales? capaz tenes algun caracter sucio (suele pasar que el \0 se cambia de lugar)

Answer (score 1):

Cuando haces el scanf te falta un "&" en "&auxNick".

¿has importado la librería `<string.h>`?

A mí me funciona con este código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct sUsuario{
char nickUsuario[26];
};
typedef struct sUsuario sUsuario; // DeclaraciÛn del tipo conjunto

void modificarUsuarios(sUsuario input[],int cantidad); 

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    sUsuario input[200];
    fflush(stdin);

    scanf("%s", &input[100].nickUsuario);
    modificarUsuarios(input, 200);
}
void modificarUsuarios(sUsuario input[],int cantidad) //sUsuario es el tipo de 
estructura que estoy utilizando
{
    int i;
    char auxNick[26];
    printf("ingrese Nombre de nick que desea modificar");
    scanf("%s", &auxNick);

    for(i=0; i<cantidad; i++)
    {  
        if(strcmp(input[ i ].nickUsuario,auxNick)==0) 
        {
           printf("Se ha encontrado el usuario en la posición: %d", i);
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: No, las lecturas de las cadenas está bien sin ampersand
Las cadenas son punteros y un puntero no necesita asignación en memoria.
El error está en otro lado